# Simulation of OCC, for a 3 phase Alternator using MATLAB/Simulink

Tags: simulation, matlab, electric-machine, alternator

I was wondering if there was a way simulate a 3 phase alternator on MATLAB/Simulink and obtain its Open Circuit Characteristics by conducting an Open Circuit test.

Also is there any other possible software tool,on which it could be simulated if it cannot be done on MATLAB/Simulink?

Comment: Are you asking about simulating an open-circuit test or using the OCC obtained using a test to simulate operational performance?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I would like to simulate an open-circuit test and obtain the OCC.

Answer (score 1):

The toolbox Matlab offer to simulate power system with Simulink is 
[Simscape Power Systems](http://www.mathworks.com/products/simpower/).  This toolbox is more oriented toward simulating a power network than the transformer itself. Infortunaly, Matlab doesn't come with out of the box solution for that problem.

Solidworks seem to offer a suit to simulate electromagnetic system with one of their [toolbox](https://www.solidworks.com/sw/products/details.htm?productid=2505) .

The main problem with Solidwork is that it costs a lot of money. So the most pragmatic solution would be simulate with Matlab code or FEMM, or depending on the scale of the project either go with an already made solution or if you just want to get the transformer characteristic, do the experimentation in real life.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for your reply. I shall try exploring all the possibilities in Simulink, if I am not able to achieve the results I need, I will use FEM.

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the open-circuit characteristics of an electric generator or motor, it is necessary to simulate the magnetic circuit. To do that the geometric configuration must be known and the software must be capable of simulating the magnetic flux in the magnetic material and air gap. The design details of the motor would be needed including the winding information, the magnetic material specifications and the geometric details. I believe this requires something lik a finite element analysis software.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. All right then I shall try simulating the flux, magnetic material and the air gap with the perfect geometries on COMSOL. That kind of FEM software could work.